# Size US Capital Account

Tags: foreign-exchange

I am not able to find the size of the capital account within the balance of payments for the US. Only "net" numbers, does anyone know the size of both sides of this account? They both seam to be approx 1 trillion on the current account.

Comment: What do you mean by both sides of this account, capital account does not have two sides, you want the components?

Comment: @1muflon1 there is inflow and out flows right? I can only find the difference between the two. Just as imports and exports in the current account

Comment: capital account tracks the ownership of domestic foreign assets - it’s not really accurate to describe these as flows. Changes in this account result from non-market activities or more often changes in a disposal of nonproduced, nonfinancial or intangible assets and similar stuff like debt forgiveness. That’s why I asked for clarification because you can definitely find data on for example how much intellectual property US firms got from abroad, or how much debt was forgiven in a given year and so on but that does not seem to fit the question as you posed it

Comment: @1muflon1 https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/031615/whats-difference-between-current-account-and-capital-acc

Comment: the link you shared gives 404 error - also investopedia is not really good source as it is not very accurate when it comes to macroeconomics or international economics- the description I mentioned in the comment comes from the textbook by Krugman et al. International trade: theory and policy

Comment: @1muflon1 Sorry fixed https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/031615/whats-difference-between-current-account-and-capital-account.asp

Comment: Gross flows are extremely large, and probably meaningless. For example, a hyperactive Canadian trader could buy/sell large amounts of American equities all day, with the net flows being nearly zero, but the gross flows being a multiple of the portfolio size.

Comment: @Brian Romanchuck good point..I wanted to get some idea how large impact trade vs finicial assets demand had on the dollar

Comment: I suspect you either want pages 19-24 of https://www.bea.gov/system/files/2020-03/trans419.pdf for the financial account of the US Balance of Payments (flows) or page 7 of https://www.bea.gov/sites/default/files/2020-03/intinv419_1.pdf for the US International Investment Position (levels of assets and liabilities).  What the IMF and US Government call the "Capital Account" can be found at the bottom of page 9 of the first link, but it is obscure and small and almost certainly not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Henry I looked at these papers, I just want a number as on page 2 for the currcent account

Comment: Page 3 says "Fourth quarter transactions increased U.S. residents’ foreign financial assets by \$1.0billion.... Fourth quarter transactions increased U.S. liabilities to foreign residents by \$71.9billion." Also in the table on page 10

Comment: @Henry thats still a bunch of "nets" and no aggregate number.